# Why I am getting logged out from gnome session when i insert any usb drive or unmount any usb drive

Tags: fedora, usb-drive, gnome-shell

OS - Fedora 27
Kernel - 4.14.14-300.fc27.x86_64

Whenever I plug in any usb drive or try to unmount an already plugged in usb drive I get logged out from gnome session. After logging back in again, I can access the drive and work normally.
Why is this happening?
Please inform me if I need to attach an kind of log.

Comment: Are you unmounting from the terminal? If not can you try and see if you can unmount successfully using `umount /dev/sdX`. Want to know if gnome is the problem or just unmounting is.

Comment: Same results with umount @Hunter.S.Thompson

Answer (score 0):

`gnome-shell` is probably crashing.

I don't know if it's installed by default in fedora, but you can try to run `coredumpctl` to see if you have any traces here. If it's the case that crash should be reported to fedora

EDIT: The output of `journalctl --user` would be interesting as well

Comment: Then why would umount also create problem?

Comment: There are probably events sent when (un)mounting that are received by gnome-shell

Comment: this is the output from journalctl --user
https://hastebin.com/raw/civanomebe
@Bigon

Comment: You have nothing beore that?

Comment: that's the output from `journalctl --user -r`   before that there is nothing interesting.
that's when i plugged in my usb drive.

Comment: Do you have the `Places Status Indicator` extension installed? You can try to disable it maybe? Apparently it could be the cause of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an incompatibility between the current version of the Gnome Shell in Fedora (*) and the following Gnome Extensions:

- Places Status Indicator
- Removable Drive Menu

So as a workaround you can switch these extensions off, at least until a real bugfix is provided by the Fedora team.

(*) More precisely, it's a problem in gjs package. As I just found out there is an updated package version available, but it hasn't even reached updates-testing yet. But you could give

```
dnf install https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/gjs/1.50.4/1.fc27/x86_64/gjs-1.50.4-1.fc27.x86_64.rpm
```

a try.

Addendum 2018-02-07: The fixed version of `gjs` is now available as regular update, so simply updating Fedora should help.